# Configure Windows Media Service on windows server 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003

I try to use Windows media service on windows 2003 for unicast.
after adding a publish point and create annouce file, I can view video on my local machin,but when I try to open it from the web, video can't play.
what setting I must do to can view content from remote pcs.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AS you can view it locally it suggest that the streaming service itself is working ok, it could be a firewall problem that is affecting connections from outside. [This article](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windowsmedia/forpros/serve/firewall.aspx) from Microsoft provides allot of useful information for configuring firewalls for Windows media streaming.

Comment: Thanks,I disable firewall, but still I can't view video from rempote.

Answer (score 1):

Try playing the video on Windows Media Player on the braodcasting server. If the video plays successfully, it means that there are security constraints (perhaps a firewall?) on the server that is disallowing outgoing connections or these limitations are present on your computer.